# Prestashop - migrate module 1.7 -> 1.6 (field name is empty)

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I created module for prestashop 1.7 and this code working (class extend: ModuleFrontControllerCore)

```
$newProduct = new Product();
$newProduct->name = 'Example name';
$newProduct->reference = '123456789';
$newProduct->active = false;
```

next I wanted migrate module to 1.6 and I changed:

```
$newProduct = new ProductCore();
$newProduct->name = [(int)ConfigurationCore::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'Example name'];
$newProduct->reference = '123456789';
$newProduct->active = false;
```

The product is added but the name is missing in the catalog.. Where is error?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$default_lang = ConfigurationCore::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
$newProduct = new ProductCore();
$newProduct->name = [$default_lang => 'Example name'];
$newProduct->link_rewrite = [$default_lang => ToolsCore::link_rewrite('Example name')];
$newProduct->reference = '123456789';
$newProduct->active = false;
```